# ImportError: no module named 'cv2' con Lego EV3

Tags: python, opencv

estoy programando un robot lego con python y necesito utilizar la librería opencv.
Estoy iniciándome por lo que aún no lo domino bien.
Versión de python 3.10

Si programo por separado me funciona perfecto el robot y la librería de opencv, el error es al juntarlo todo.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

El código inicial sería:

````
#librerias opencv
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp

#librerias lego

from pybricks.hubs import EV3Brick
from pybricks.ev3devices import (Motor, TouchSensor, ColorSensor,
                                 InfraredSensor, UltrasonicSensor, GyroSensor)
from pybricks.parameters import Port, Stop, Direction, Button, Color
from pybricks.tools import wait, StopWatch, DataLog
from pybricks.robotics import DriveBase
from pybricks.media.ev3dev import SoundFile, ImageFile




#inicializar ev3
ev3 = EV3Brick()

#inicializar motor en el puerto b
test_motorB=Motor(Port.B)
test_motorC=Motor(Port.C)


mp_drawing=mp.solutions.drawing_utils #permite dibujar las conexiones de la mano
mp_hands=mp.solutions.hands```

El error que obtengo es:

``` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/robot/prueba2/main.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: no module named 'cv2' ```
````

Comment: Dentro del sdk del lego esta incluida la biblioteca cv2?, o no?.

Comment: Mejor dicho, has intentado instalar el modulo cv2 en el robot?. cv2 no viene por defecto en python. Creo que deberias descargarlo he instalarlo en el bot.

Comment: @DABL03 perdona mi ignorancia, pero como podría realizar eso?? He flasheado una sd con el bot de lego para que funcione, pero no sé como poder incluir la libreria de opencv en el

Comment: Intenta conectar tu bot a la computadora, usa tu terminal. Si tienes instalado pip puedes usarlo: pip install opencv-python . Ya instalado intenta importarla dentro del bot y ve los resultados. Sino esta instalado pip puedes instalarlo: python -m ensurepip --upgrade